# Prove $det(A^2+B^2+C^2)+2det(AB+BC+CA)\ge 0$, for real-valued pairwise commuting 2x2 matrices A,B,C.

Tags: matrices

I tried to use the fact that, for 2x2 matrices, $f(\lambda)=\det(U+\lambda B)$ can be expressed as a polynomial $f(\lambda)=\lambda^2\det B + \lambda z + \det A$, for some constant $z$. If we take $U=A^2+B^2+C^2$ and $V=AB+BC+CA$, then I can prove that $f(2)\ge 0$ and $f(-1)\ge 0$ using factorization given that matrices are commuting and also the fact that for commuting matrices $\det(A^2+B^2)\ge 0$.
I don't know how to proceed further. Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

*Hints.* There are two possibilities:

1. One of the three matrices, say $A$, has a conjugate pair of non-real eigenvalues. By a similarity transform, we may assume that $A=cR$ for some scalar $c\ne0$ and some rotation matrix $R\ne\pm I$. Now observe that $R$ only commutes with scalar multiples of rotation matrices, and the sums or products of scalar multiples of $2\times2$ rotation matrices are again scalar multiples of rotation matrices.
2. All of the three matrices have real spectra. Hence they form a commuting family of triangulable matrices over $\mathbb R$. In turn, they are simultaneously triangulable. Assume that they are upper triangular. The inequality now reduces to
   $$
   (a_{11}^2+b_{11}^2+c_{11}^2)(a_{22}^2+b_{22}^2+c_{22}^2)
   +2(a_{11}b_{11}+b_{11}c_{11}+c_{11}a_{11})(a_{22}b_{22}+b_{22}c_{22}+c_{22}a_{22})
   \ge0
   $$
   and you may continue from here.